# Is "quaternary" adjective redundant while speaking of InGaAsP?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronics, electronic-band-theory, nanoscience

I'm reading an article. One sentence looks as following:

> The 500 nm
>   thick waveguide layer consists of an InGaAsP quaternary layer

But since InGaAsP is quaternary compound, why do they write that its layer is quaternary? Is there some extra knowledge behind that, which I don't know of?

Article in question: https://research.tue.nl/en/publications/the-243-steps-of-making-photonic-integrated-circuits-in-inp

Comment: In that specific sentence it could be considered redundant, but it could also serve a clarifying role in relation to other sentences in the paper. Being concise should not come at the expense of being clear.

Answer (score 0):

It could have been a multilayer, so pointing out that it is a quaternary compound helps to clarify.